# Arcmap with javascript

Tags: arcgis

am new to GIS stuff. Am trying to build a map using ArcMap and publish it to my ArcGIS server. I need to pass dynamic coordinates and pop up content to the map  service. Any advice on how it can be done is appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth asking this on gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

[resources.esri.com](http://resources.esri.com) would be a good place to start. The ArcGIS for Server resource documents provide introductory tutorials for creating and publishing map services. This should help give you a general overview and perhaps lead you in the right direction.